# Why can’t VLC go in to fullscreen mode?

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, vlc

I’m working on a Matlab application that uses a VLC class to control a VLC-instance. One of the features is to set the VLC player to fullscreen. This feature works perfectly fine.

The VLC player is downloaded from Matlab’s File Exchange: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56215-vlc (Thanks a lot Léa Strobino)

However, one particular clip insists on resizing the player to a **smaller size**.
I have done some research and it turns out that this is a common problem in some VLC versions.

Normal workarounds are to uncheck the “adapt interface to video size” (something like that) and to **check the “Fullscreen” box**. 
This ought to make the player open in fullscreen and not resize the screen to video size. The video still resizes the player to a smaller size.

All the specs of the clips are the same: Same file extension (.vob), formats and were made the same way (I did some video trimming and such using ffmpeg – but the same way every time).

I have noticed one difference and that is that this particular video has a lower Data and bitrate (~1000-1500kbps) where as the others are higher (<4000kbps). Also when showing the properties of the clip the frame height and width are blank as opposed to the others that have specific values.

This should however not have an effect of the fullscreen command from Matlab called ***after*** loading the video into the playlist. The command has no effect on this video, but does on all other.

It is possible to set the player to fullscreen manually by clicking the window, so it is not caused by some restriction in the video not allowing it to fullscreen.

Why does the video refuse to go in to fullscreen?

Hope somebody is able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I seem to have solved the problem now. Without being completely sure why - the problem was in the lowered data/framerate.

I tried to add **-crf 18** when converting my .mp4 to a .vob file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec ac3 -crf 18 output.vob
```

The -crf stands for *Constant Rate Factor* and is a way to ensure a specific Data rate. The values goes from 0-51 and 18 seems to be the lowest 'sane' value (highest data rate). A good explanation can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/677576/what-is-crf-used-for-in-ffmpeg

With this higher data rate the video opens up in fullscreen everytime :=)